# How to launch and keep a background process inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, dockerfile

I need to launch a background job (Google SQL Proxy) inside a Docker container (actually an AppEngine image).

After some struggle with it I discovered that trying to launch the background job either discards the job the moment I detach from container (see RUN command in script) or the container stops working properly (see CMD command in script)

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM eu.gcr.io/google-appengine/ubuntu-php56

ADD ./run.sh /app
RUN chmod 777 /app/run.sh
#RUN nohup /app/run.sh & #This is lost the moment I finished creation of container
CMD nohup /app/run.sh & #This crash the container
```

Here is the run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 echo "Beep"
 sleep 2
done
```

Here is the command to build the Docker image:

```
docker image build --tag red .
```

Here is the command to create the docker container:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name red1 red
```

Here is how I connect to container to check what's inside

```
docker exec -it red1 /bin/bash
```

Once again my target is to be able to lunch and keep run.sh running all the time.

Comment: And do your want to run any other processes in the container?

Comment: have you tried to run command manually once you enter bash?

Comment: @Ignacio Millan I simply want to add one or more background processes to my container.

Comment: @Tree Yes, and it worked as it had to.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, there is no need to run sql proxy in appengine, you can connect directly to your database instance.

Anyway, the container exists because every container needs one (and just one) foreground process. Changing the CMD to run any other process in the foreground makes the work:

```
CMD nohup /app/run.sh & sleep infinity
```

In this case the foreground process is sleep, you can change it for the process that runs your app.

Comment: My application is split between the PHP code running in a Docker container inside the AppEngine and my database is in Cloud SQL. Until now I saw no other option to connect to the Cloud SQL from my container other than SQL Proxy.

Comment: AppEngine provides an Unix socket to connect directly to cloudSQL. Here is an example with Python: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/cloudsql

Comment: AppEngine provides an Unix socket but only for standard AppEngine apps. I have a custom runtime based on a Docker image Google provides ( https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/ ) and it seems that no, you do not have a Unix socket pre-installed inside that Google Docker image so you have to add it somehow.

Comment: Ok then I think is possible to connect directly via TCP, or use SQL proxy with this CMD

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the ENTRYPOINT command to do that.
Have a look to the doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Comment: ENTRYPOINTS seems to be for the cases when you want to add parameters or other commands to your container. I simply want to be able to launch some background jobs (run.sh in my example)

Answer (score 0):

To act as a Cloud SQL Proxy I reccomend to use separate docker image, that is available with this command:

```
docker pull gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.12
```

You can run it with following command:

```
docker run -d \
  -v <PATH_TO_KEY_FILE>:/config \
  -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
  gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.12 /cloud_sql_proxy \
  -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/config
```

This is an example for the Postgress. For MySQL use 3306 port.

[For step by step configuration including all needed scopes and permissions please check documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-docker).